# PHP Laravel route resource to get request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to send a message form and route resource to show by search bar.

But it does not appear, what wrong in my code?

```html
<form method="GET" action="articles/">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" name="name">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button  class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

here is route

```html
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

here is controller

```html
 public function show($id){

  $article = Article::find($id);

  if(empty($article))

  abort(404);

  return view('articles.show', compact('article'));

 }
```

Comment: do you want to search by id or search by name?

Comment: so input in your form "name", what do you want that for? just to display name in your view?

Comment: after i submit form url so
http://localhost:8000/articles/?name=dsadasd
it don't enter show method

Comment: when you submit that form your route will call index function not the show function your url needs to look like this /articles/{article} to call show method. have a look at Actions Handled By Resource Controller in https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers,

so to search article with id 1 your url should look like localhost:8000/articles/1 this is call show method

Comment: but 1 is come form get url not rewrite

Comment: also localhost:8000/articles/?id=1

Comment: I tried this code in my local, data is passing to the index() function in ArticlesController. Did u figured it out the solution?

Comment: thx u am get for solution